# When I click `l` in the Windows 2008, the system will locked, but not type out the `l`

Tags: windows-server-2008

I use MICROSOFT REMOTE DESKTOP to connect the windows 2008 server in my mac.
When I click `l` in the Windows 2008, the system will locked, but not type out the `l`.

The picture is after I click the `l` keyboard.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is opposite from the normal behavior where, from [Get Started with Remote Desktop on Mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-mac#navigating-the-remote-desktop-session):

> Mac keyboard layouts differ from the Windows keyboard layouts. The OS
>   keyboard locale is suggested to the remote PC. If the OS keyboard
>   locale is not used, we recommend checking the keyboard setting on the
>   remote PC and changing the setting manually.
>
> - The Command key on the
>     Mac keyboard equals the Windows key.
> - To perform actions that use the Command button on the Mac, you will need to use the control button in
>     Windows (e.g.: Copy = Ctrl + C).
> - The function keys can be activated in the session by pressing
>     additionally the FN key (e.g.: FN + F1).
> - The Alt key to the right of
>     the space bar on the Mac keyboard equals the Alt Gr/right Alt key in
>     Windows.

So, you are normally using **`Command+L`** to do this. Pressing Command usually fixes this problem with Sticky Windows Key.